# server registers ip of my modem continously to use it in my android application

Tags: java, android, webserver

Initially, ip-addresses from  the ISP are always changing. I am working on an android app and I need to connect from outside my home to my internal network. I need a server connected to my modem/router and the server should save the public ip of my home network every time it changes.

**Goal:** make a communication between my android app and the modem/router.

**My question is:**
Do I have to program an app on the server side to do this job, or is there an app already available?

If none are available, could you please tell me the steps to create one, or any references to that end?

Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

I think your best bet is to use a dynamic dns service.  That will allow you to give your machine a string name, run the app they'll give you (or many routers support this built-in), and just reference the computer by name when you need it.  See http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dynamic_DNS